# Update older records when a new column is added

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2005

In my system, the client will fill in their information to register an account.  For new registrations, the record will contain a new check-box option.

My Question is, how do I update the old records so that they contain a checked value for the check-box option that has been added?

My supervisor suggest I patch the data but I'm not sure where to start with this.

Comment: please share the schema of the columns in the table that you have added and their defaults.

Comment: so you want to add a new column of type bit to your table and you want to have all existing records have the value 1 in this new column ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to add a new bit column to an existing table and want all existing records have the value 1 in it.
To do this you first create the new column and than right after set all existing records to 1

```
alter table MyTable
add CheckedField bit

update MyTable set CheckedField = 1
```

If the new column is mandatory than you can do it like this :

```
alter table MyTable
add CheckedField bit not null default (1)
```

Comment: It helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got your question. You need to add few Boolean fields to your existing table with **DEFAULT** value TRUE.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 add checkField bit default 1
```

You need to map the corresponding field to a check box in your UI. For existing client it will checked as the field is set true in database.